# How to implement Inherited interfaces in C#

Tags: c#

I am not sure what this is called so I most likely calling it wrong when I say `Inherited interface`. Here is what I am trying to achieve.

I have an interface like this

```
 public interface INotificationEngine
    {
        bool UsingDbMail();

        bool UsingSMTP();

        bool UsingSMS();
    }
```

My class looks like this

```
 public class NotificationEngine
    {
        public class Send : INotificationEngine
        {
            public bool UsingDbMail(string para)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool UsingSMTP()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool UsingSMS()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

That allows me to do something like the following

```
NotificationEngine.Send sendRequest = new NotificationEngine.Send();
sendRequest.UsingDbMail("hello");
```

What I want to achieve instead is the following

```
NotificationEngine engine = new NotificationEngine();
engine.UsingDbMail("hello").Send;
```

Any idea how can I do that with interfaces or any other way?

Comment: `UsingDbMail()` is returning a `bool`, and a boolean value does not have the property `Send`. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Presumably you meant you want `engine.UsingDbMail("hello").Send();` (a method named `Send` on an object returned by the `UsingSomething` methods); have an interface with the `Send` member exposed, and have your `UsingXyz` methods return an object that implements this interface.

Comment: Like, `public IMailerService UsingDbMail(string body)`, and then have a `class DbMailerService : IMailerService` and then you'll have a `SmtpMailerService : IMailerService`, and so on.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you are a super genius :) thank you so much, that does it. Not sure why I did not think of that - Post as answer please so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Posted from phone, took a little while but, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your common interface, it probably needs to look something like this:

```
interface IMailerService
{
    bool Send ():
}
```

You'll want an implementation that uses dbmail, another for SMTP, and another for SMS. Construct an instance of these classes in each of your "UsingXyz" methods (note: no need for a nested class here):

```
public IMailerService UsingDbMail(...)
{
    return new DbMailerService(...);
}

public IMailerService UsingSmtp(...)
{
    return new SmtpMailerService(...);
}

public IMailerService UsingSms(...)
{
    return new SmsMailerService(...)
}
```

Now when you call a UsingXyz method, you get an object that exposes a `Send` method that it implements as needed:

```
engine.UsingSms(...).Send(); // sends a SMS message
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks so much